# How to get data of every first day of month for all month in my sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table samples. It has data of every day of every month

```
  date         m1   m2   m3
'2017-01-01'   10   11    12
'2017-01-02'   10   10    12
'2017-01-03'   10   11    12
'2017-01-04'   10   8     12
'2017-02-01'   10   6     12
'2017-02-02'   10   14    12
```

I want the data like this

```
 date         m1   m2   m3
'2017-01-01'   10   11   12
'2017-02-01'   10   6    12
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE DAY(date) = '01'`

Comment: Fix your schema design. I would expect to see the following columns: sample_id, date, m_no, m_value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following querys

```
select * from your_table_name
where `date`= DATE_FORMAT(`date` ,'2017-%m-01')
```

or

```
select * from your_table_name
where DAY(`date`)= '01' and YEAR(`date`)='2017'
```

Note that this will return records of every first day of months for the year 2017

Comment: Its working but i am only desirous to get the data of year 2017 only? So should i add %y in the DATE_FORMAT() ?

Comment: @Ashutoshdwivedi see the updated answer as your requirement.

Comment: I can also pass year specifier in date format function as well to fullfill my need.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from `Table` WHERE date_format(date,"%d") = '01'
```

Comment: It is working but i am getting all years that are stored in my table. Can't we get data of year 2017 only?

Comment: In case of that you just specify year filter by SELECT * from `Table` WHERE date_format(date,"%d") = '01' and date_format(date,"%y") = '2017'

Comment: @Ashutoshdwivedi i request you to update the question properly